# How can I get the hidden layers for each indiviual head?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I know we can access the hidden layer from each layer by the following code. However, each hidden output we obtains is the result mixed from 12 head by a fully connected layers. Is there a way to obtain the outputs before they enter the fully connected layers?

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig

config = BertConfig.from_pretrained("xxx", output_hidden_states=True)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("xxx", config=config)

outputs = model(inputs)
print(len(outputs))  # 3

hidden_states = outputs[2]
```

Thank you!

Comment: You mean the outputs of the Bertembedding layers?

Comment: Thanks for helping!! But sorry where is "Bertembedding"? Each hidden layer output in Bert can be considered as word embedding from BERT. We have input -> split into head, For each head we apply attention using Q W V matrix, the resulting vector from each head is concatenated and passed into fully connected layer. I want the vector before it got passed into the fully connected layer.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if we have the same terminology. When you call `model.parameters`, you will get a list of layers. Can you please tell me which layer output you want to receive based on the names listed in this output?